# Troubleshooting ORA-00942

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00942

In the middle of an automated test run last night, one of my twenty worker threads blew out; the application was attempting an INSERT.  Springframework reports ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

Connecting to the database (11.1.0.6.0) through the enterprise manager, I pull up a SQL worksheet and query the table, discovering (a) that the table exists now (b) the row that should have been inserted is missing (c) the row previously inserted by this thread is present (d) that the table has rows before and after the error in time.

For a user with little oracle experience, how do I verify that the error originated with this database server, and from there how do I walk the error back to a root cause?

Comment: Could you supply this additional information:  1. Were the inserts performed by the table owner or by another schema that had INSERT privileges?  2. If another schema was inserting into the table, was the table reference qualified by owner, accessed through a private synonym, or accessed through a public synonym?  3. Does this database have other schemas that contain tables with the same name?  There have been problems with Oracle when certain of these conditions are met - don't know if the bug is still present in 11g.

Answer (score 1):

I would start as close to the database as possible, to confirm what SQL is executed, committed, rolled back etc. in the database itself. I'd set up TKPROF (check the docs, or visit [Tom Kyte's site](http://asktom.oracle.com) for more info) and see what actually gets executed from your app. That will at least help you to see if what you expect to be executed is actually "arriving" as it should.

An ORA-00942 will occur if the table is "invisible" to the calling programme i.e. if the permissions are not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave K said, the table may have existed, but became "invisible" to your process.

Because of the phrase "last night", my thoughts lead that there may be a nightly process, like a backup or clean-up process, which caused the table to be taken offline.

Comment: An interesting thought, but I believe eliminated by point (d).  The window around the failure is pretty short (on the order of seconds).  I've actually got a row with the same timestamp that the failed insert ought to have had, submitted by a different thread.

That said, how would I track down the root cause if the problem were that the table became invisible?

Comment: Tough to say without knowing your environment. In my office I would talk to the DBAs or sysAdmins to see if any process regularly runs at that time. Also ask if there are any db logs.