# Oracle query Error ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, not-exists

I have a problem with query:

```
select * from registry$history;
```

As a result I get an error:

> ORA-00942
>   00942. 00000 - "table or view doesn exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line:1 Column: 14

Server: XP
DB - oracle 10.2.0.5 32bit

I connect to server as SYSTEM user.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609484/troubleshooting-ora-00942?rq=1) might help you

Comment: `registry$history`is in which schema?

Comment: I found the answer: select * from sys.registry$history; . But now I have a problem with history. When I use OPatch lsinvetory I get:
Interim patches (1):
Patch 10155843:.....
But in query I get a "no rows selected". Whats wrong? @Polppan

Comment: [DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4057.htm), which I think is the same information, says it only shows CPUs (though I think it actually has PSUs too, perhaps). My understanding is that it's updated by `catbundle`, which wouldn't be run for a single patch? But are you saying there is no data at all, not just that the specific patch isn't shown?

Comment: @AlexPoole I think DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY the same. Alse I added screenshot. I don't know how it was installed the patch!

Comment: @AlexPoole I checked catbundle.sql if DB was updated by catbundle the information about it's will be added to regisrty$history;

Comment: As this is not really related to the original question about ORA-00942, and patching isn't on-topic here, I think you should ask a new question about the relationship between patches and the registry history on [DBA.SE].